# Use of keyword symbols in property lists

Tags: symbols, property-lists, keywords

According to the Emacs Lisp manual http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html

> A symbol whose name starts with a colon (‘:’) is called a keyword
>   symbol. These symbols automatically act as constants, and are normally
>   used only by comparing an unknown symbol with a few specific
>   alternatives.

and http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Lists.html#Property-Lists

> A property list (plist for short) is a list of paired elements. Each
>   of the pairs associates a property name (usually a symbol) with a
>   property or value.

What is the difference between:

```
(let ((my-plist '(bar t foo 4)))
  (plist-get my-plist 'foo))
```

and

```
(let ((my-plist '(bar t :foo 4)))
  (plist-get my-plist :foo))
```

and which one is preferred?

Comment: I guess you mean `'(:bar t :foo 4)` in the second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference to my knowledge. You can see `:foo` as an auto-quoting `'foo`.  Keyword arguments show more clearly that they are constants, so you should use them if you want to do that.

You can also experiment with this if you like:

```cl
(let (cands)
  (mapatoms (lambda (x)
              (when (string-match "foobarbaz" (symbol-name x))
                (push x cands))))
  cands)
```

The initial eval should return nil.
But after you eval `(list :foobarbaz)`, it will change.
After you eval `(list 'foobarbaz)`, it will change once more.

Comment: Thanks, then I will use keyword symbols in property lists since it makes it more clear what is the property name and what is its value..