# Colon in Emacs Lisp

Tags: property-lists

I came across [this](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/01/24/Modern-use-of-helm-sortable-candidates/) example:

```
(setq h-data '((:num 1 :key "apple")
               (:num 9 :key "berry")
               (:num 2 :key "cactus")
               (:num 5 :key "dog")
               (:num 4 :key "frog")))
```

The source said that this is a property list. So, I looked up the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Lists.html#Property-Lists) and did not notice any syntax using a colon. What is this syntax? Is `:num` different from `'num`? Where is this syntax described in the manual?

Comment: You probably mean "colon", not "column". See [Symbol Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html).

Comment: Oh, thank you. That is the reason I could not find it :)

Comment: @choroba: please post your comment as an answer (with a little bit more that explains what a keyword is).

Comment: @Dan With the change, my question is a duplicate of this (just found now): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12142/16048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Symbol Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html):

> A symbol whose name starts with a colon (`:`) is called a keyword symbol. These symbols automatically act as constants, and are normally used only by comparing an unknown symbol with a few specific alternatives. See [Constant Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Constant-Variables.html#Constant-Variables).